# How to make a "dot function" in javascript

Tags: javascript, function

I'm trying to define a "dot function" where there are no parameters but has a `.` and a string or number before it like these:

> .toUpperCase()
> .toLowerCase()
> .indexOf()
> .charAt()
> .substring()

You do `2..toString`, not `toString(2)`.

How do you define one of them?

Comment: This is not recommended. What if the official specification later defines a function with the same name but a different meaning?

Comment: Then you have to add any external methods to the prototype of objects

Comment: They'd have to be methods of an object and not everything behaves in a way that this would work for.

Comment: in any case, `2.toString()` is invalid syntax. You would have to use `2..toString()`

Comment: you are finding prototype

Comment: Oops! That was a typo. I fixed it now.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Defining a "dot function" is easy. Here's how you can define it on a single object.

```
var a = {}, or a = function() {}, or a = [], etc.

a.dotFunction = function() { return 'hi'; }

console.log(a.dotFunction());
```

If you want to define it on all instances of a "class", use `prototype`.

```
function someClass() {
}

someClass.prototype.dotFunction = function() { return 'hi'; };

console.log(new someClass().dotFunction());
```

You can even do this on built-in types (some, like Prototype.js, do this, though most recommended against it).

```
Number.prototype.dotFunction = function() { return 'hi'; };

console.log((0).dotFunction());
```

Answer (score 19):

I'd strongly recommend not trying to replace any built-in methods, however, you're free to define your own methods however you like.

You can do this by attaching the method to the `Number` or `String` type's prototype:

```
Number.prototype.foo = function(n) { return this * n; };
String.prototype.bar = function(n) { return this.length * n; };

alert(4..foo(2));  // 8
alert("4".bar(2)); // 2
```

**Further Reading**

- [Inheritance and the prototype chain](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Inheritance_and_the_prototype_chain)

Comment: And you're not going to include any of the reasons why it's often bad to add methods to the built-in types?  Also, why two periods in your first `alert()`?

Comment: @jfriend00 I think JS parser needs 2 dots otherwise with only one lookahead it can't decide if its a fractional number or a dot for method access with only a single dot.

Answer (score -1):

I'll give it a shot because nobody mentioned that you can already do this without having to define anything yourself.

A thing to take care of is if you have a number you have to place 2 dots after it where as if you have a function that returns a number or a variable that holds one you don't:

```
1..toString()
 .indexOf("1")//<=returns number 0
 //even though a number is returned we only need one dot here
 .toString();//<="0"

var num = 1234;
num.toString()//<=one dot
  .indexOf("23");//<=1
```

Your example would already work but since `indexOf` would return a number if you give it an argument that makes sense and a number doesn't have a `charAt` method.

```
"hello".toUpperCase()
  .toLowerCase()
  .indexOf("h")//<=returns a number 
               //number has no charAt method
  .toString()
  .charAt(0)
  .substring(0);//<="0"
```