# Dot function in python?

Tags: python, function, user-defined-functions

I once stumbled upon [this StackOverflow page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19872917/how-to-make-a-dot-function-in-javascript), when I was learning JavaScript. It taught me how to make a function that can be called by writing something like `35.myFunction(parameter)`

Now, I've added Python to my cache of languages, and can't figure out how to accomplish the same thing in python.

**To be more precise:** **I would like to make a python function that can be called with a value and a dot before it.**

For example: `"Hello World?".replace("?", "!")`

If someone could tell me how to make such a function, and give an example, I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: What do you want this "dot function" to accomplish? Do you have specific kinds of values you want to operate on? Do you want to be able to write `.replace(x, y)` after _anything_?

Comment: "I am reminded of something Wolsey once told me, that I should only ever tell the king what he ought to do, not what he could do; for if the lion knows his own strength, no man could control him." -- Thomas More.  Just because you can do something in a language definitely does not mean you *should.*

Comment: I don't really care what type of value it operates on. For example's sake, I'd like it to add 2 to an integer.
For example: `x = 5` and then `x.myFunction()` makes x equal to 7.

Answer (score 4):

You can't do so for arbitrary types, since types defined in C cannot have arbitrary attributes added to them. However:

```
class C(object):
  pass

def do_something(self):
  print self.__name__

o = C()
C.printname = do_something

o.printname()
```