# There is a way to create a generic function for literal Object?

Tags: javascript

I would like to create a function that can be used by every of my literal object and refer to the `caller` with `this` argument.

Something like that:

```
const literalObject = { 
    "value" : "string"
}

const genricFunction = () =>{
    console.log("value : ",this.value)
}

literalObject.genricFunction()
```

Comment: You can add a property to the `Object.prototype` object, which is a practice that many people would say is a bad idea. That's how you'd do it though.

Comment: See [How to make a “dot function” in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19872917/1715579)

Comment: I Have tried but ".this" return "null"

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this

```
function obj() {
    this.value = 'string'
}

obj.prototype.getValue = function() {
   return this.value
}

let myObj = new obj()
myObj.getValue(); // 'string'
```

Comment: This is the best way to do it, but you could improve this answer by adding some explanation and using the same names as the OP (`myObj` -> `literalObject` and `getValue` -> `genricFunction`) so that they can map it to their question more easily.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
const obj ={genricFunction:function(){console.log("value : ",this.value)}}
```

And then create every object like this:

```
const newObj = Object.create(obj)
newObj.value=“string”
```

Answer (score 0):

You can assign your generic function to the `Object.prototype`. Here's your updated code.

```
const literalObject = { 
    "value" : "string"
}

const genericFunction = function() {
    console.log("value : ",this.value)
}

Object.prototype.genericFunction = genericFunction

literalObject.genricFunction()
```

Although this will work, this is considered as bad practice. What is the usecase you want this for, maybe we can suggest you a better way.

Comment: It works but strange thing, when I use `() =>` instead of `function ()`, `.this` point on the Window element.

Comment: @MrRock That's not strange, that's the main difference between arrow functions and regular functions (arrow functions don't get a `this` when they're called, so `this` just references the same this as the next lexical scope).

Answer (score -1):

You can create the `literalObject` and the `genericFunction` :

```
const literalObject = { 
    "value" : "string"
}

const genricFunction = function () {
    console.log("value : ",this.value)
}
```

and then assign a property to the `literalObject` with bound `genericFunction`:

```
literalObject.genericFunction = genricFunction.bind(literalObject);
```

and whenever you call

```
literalObject.genricFunction();
```

it will use the `literalObject` as `this`

```js
    const literalObject = { 
        "value" : "string"
    }
    
    const genricFunction = function () {
        document.write(JSON.stringify(this.value));
    }
    
    literalObject.genricFunction = genricFunction.bind(literalObject);
    
    literalObject.genricFunction();
```

Comment: This solution corresponds most to what I try to do, ty